# How to GET limited data from server using axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, axios

In the Axios `GET` request, how do I manage to get only some of the data from server. For example, I want to display various blogs stored in my database but for page number 1, I want to GET only first 10 blogs and then when the users hits page 2, I want to GET 10 blogs after the first 10 blog entries of the database.

Comment: How should we know?  This is dependent on whatever that server is and how it responds to your queries.  You should post information about that server instead.  The client you use to fetch the data isn't as relevant.

Comment: Then make your server respond to "page" queries, like adding parameters for how many records you want, what page to start on, etc.

Comment: You should control the data on server side before returning it, One way you can do it by controlling it from client is by sending query params like `/getBlogs/?page=10` and use this page value on server while returning data.

Comment: I think it is about your API pagination, not axios.

Answer (score 2):

Pagination can be used here to achieve the desired output over here.

For example, consider your blog website has a total of 5 pages as follows:
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5

So, while making request to the backend you can send **page number** and the **page size** every time a user is making a request.
Then at the backend side you can splice those many elements from database and return those to the client.

If user is requesting a page then at the backend you can write like.

```js
DATABASE_RECORDS.splice(((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize) + 1, pageSize)
```

Comment: This answer seems very promising sir, Can you please suggest an example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can take a look at this link just for reference purpose - https://www.cronj.com/blog/reactjs-pagination

Answer (score 1):

The name of that, I think so, is pagination. Here one tutorial with React [axios-React-pagination](https://medium.com/how-to-react/create-pagination-in-reactjs-e4326c1b9855). You don't need create the buttons, you can set a event when the user reach the bottom of page, then load it. You wanna se an example, ask in comments that soon I do it.

Comment: Hey , I went through your suggestion and it was great but one thing I noticed is , what you are doing is downloading all the content and then displaying it page by page, but what I would want to do is download only some content (say 10 posts) and display them and then when client hits next page, download next content and display it. Won't it be better optimized in the latter case? And for the example, I would love to see it, Anything at this moment is helpful. Thanks for the help.